# django-celery-email with rabbitMQ - Cannot connect. Socket closed

Tags: python, django, celery

I try to use django-celery-email. I use rabbitMQ

If I run: `python manage.py celeryd -l info`

I have these errors:

```
(job)user@user-R520-R522-R620:~/Pulpit/job/dp$ python manage.py celeryd -l info
/home/user/Pulpit/job/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py:71: CPendingDeprecationWarning: 
    The 'BROKER_HOST' setting is scheduled for deprecation in     version 2.5 and removal in version v4.0.     BROKER_URL

  warnings.warn(w)
/home/user/Pulpit/job/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py:71: CPendingDeprecationWarning: 
    The 'BROKER_USER' setting is scheduled for deprecation in     version 2.5 and removal in version v4.0.     BROKER_URL

  warnings.warn(w)
/home/user/Pulpit/job/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py:71: CPendingDeprecationWarning: 
    The 'BROKER_PASSWORD' setting is scheduled for deprecation in     version 2.5 and removal in version v4.0.     BROKER_URL

  warnings.warn(w)
/home/user/Pulpit/job/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py:71: CPendingDeprecationWarning: 
    The 'BROKER_PORT' setting is scheduled for deprecation in     version 2.5 and removal in version v4.0.     BROKER_URL

  warnings.warn(w)
/home/user/Pulpit/job/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py:71: CPendingDeprecationWarning: 
    The 'BROKER_VHOST' setting is scheduled for deprecation in     version 2.5 and removal in version v4.0.     BROKER_URL

  warnings.warn(w)

 -------------- celery@user-R520-R522-R620 v3.0.13 (Chiastic Slide)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- [Configuration]
-- * - **** --- . broker:      amqp://ruser@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- . app:         default:0xa8dfb2c (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader)
- ** ---------- . concurrency: 2 (processes)
- ** ---------- . events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
- ** ---------- 
- *** --- * --- [Queues]
-- ******* ---- . celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
--- ***** ----- 

[Tasks]
  . djcelery_email.tasks.SendEmailTask

[2013-01-15 20:31:23,718: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@user-R520-R522-R620 ready.
[2013-01-15 20:31:26,735: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://ruser@127.0.0.1:5672//: Socket closed.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

[2013-01-15 20:31:31,746: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://ruser@127.0.0.1:5672//: Socket closed.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds...
```

Where to find the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RabbitMQ` instance doesn't appear to be running - that's why you're seeing `consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://ruser@127.0.0.1:5672//: Socket closed.` in your error logs. Is your `RabbitMQ` instance running and accepting connections on `127.0.0.1:5672`?